# Do I need to install a separate control when hooking up an oil fired boiler to a heat pump system?

Tags: hvac

When the temp goes below a certain set point what bring the boiler on?

Comment: Do you mean as backup/assist if the heat pump can't do the job, or do you mean switching over if outside temperature goes low enough that the heat pump is struggling? I usually just set my gas boiler's thermostat to somewhere around 60 degrees, with the heat pump usually keeping things closer to 68, and trust that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Get a reasonably advanced  thermostat (not necessarily a "smart" tstat)  but  one that has an "aux heat" capability.   If the main heating system can't maintain set-point, the tstat will turn on the boiler.